# MPI: Printf Statement is not executed at the right time

Tags: c, multithreading, printf, mpi

I have a small program.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int rank, size;
int buf;
int err;
MPI_Status status;

err = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
if(err == MPI_SUCCESS) {
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if(rank == 0) {
printf("Buffer size is less than 10\n");
printf("Enter the buffer size: ");
scanf("%d", &buf);
MPI_Send(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 10,
MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else {
MPI_Recv(&buf, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 10,
MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
printf("process[%d]: buffer size : %d\n", rank,buf);

}
err = MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
[veda@home-pc hpc]$ mpicc test.c
[veda@home-pc hpc]$ mpiexec -np 2 a.out
Buffer size is less than 10
3
Enter the buffer size: process[0]: buffer size : 3
process[1]: buffer size : 3
```

In this output, you can notice that

> Enter the buffer size:

is printing/prompting after I entered the size of the buffer.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect your standard output is line-buffered. The `"Enter the buffer size: "` is not printed until `"process[%d]: buffer size : %d\n"` (containing a newline) is printed. The solution is to explicitly flush the standard output between the `printf` and the `scanf`:

```
printf("Enter the buffer size: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &buf);
```

Comment: [This page](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/nsc/lib/fflush.html) warns against doing that, saying that any input after `printf()` but before ``fflush()`` gets discarded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it:

```
puts("Enter the buffer size:");
gets(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are **using Eclipse for parallel programming**, then (most probably) that is what causes the issue. 
It is some kind of glitch in PTP. You can also experience this with `printf`, it only prints after your program has finished execution or was shut down (not while the program is running).
 **Then** try running your code from the command line, it will work. 

**Else** (*If it still gets hanged or gives weird behaviour*) **then** try calling 
`fflush(stdout)` or `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`
to flush everything before reading user input.

Answer (score -1):

Well thats what you have.

```
printf("Buffer size is less than 10\n");
printf("Enter the buffer size: ");
```

I mean what do you suspect for it to do? Look right after: `if(rank==0)` to see what I mean. In fact, you don't even use the %d you use 10.

You probably want:

```
if(rank == 0) {
   printf("Enter the buffer size: ");
   scanf("%d", &buf);
   printf("Buffer size is less than %d\n", buf);
   //...
```